# ASP.NET refresh part of web page while other web-service returns its call

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

### **WebPage.aspx**

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" onclick="Button1_Click" />

<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="1000" 
    OnTick="StatusTimer_Tick" Enabled="False" />

<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1"></asp:Label>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1"/>
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label2"></asp:Label>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" Event="Click"/>
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

### **WebPage.aspx.cs**

```
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = "Refreshed at : " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Timer1.Enabled = true;

    //Call some web-service
    XMLComparisonService.Service1SoapClient oService = new XMLComparisonService.Service1SoapClient();
    oService.XMLComparison();
}
```

1. So `Button1_Click` enables `Timer1`.
2. `Label1` in `UpdatePanel1` should get refreshed every 1 second! (with `Label1` printing the current time)
3. `Button1_Click` also calls the web-service method "XMLComparison"

But `Label1` doesnt refresh after the web-service method "XMLComparison" gets called...
Is anything wrong with my approach?

Regards
-Parag

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are calling a webservice, but not waiting for a response before updating the page.

Here is an example

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webservices/WebServiceConsumer.aspx